# Which protocol does use when calling custom defined functions on Parse Cloud?

Tags: parse-platform

Which protocol does use when calling custom defined functions on Parse Cloud ?
If it is not secured is there any already defined flag to set to be secured ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [their documentation](https://parse.com/docs/data#security-connection), all connections  are made with HTTPS and SSL, and Parse will reject any non-HTTPS connections.

The protocol used by the client libraries is HTTP, with a [REST style API](https://parse.com/docs/rest). For your custom defined (Cloud) functions, it's an HTTP POST. The body of the request is JSON.